# How to sort values for a control

Tags: amazon-quicksight

While creating a control, you need to setup control values (specific or linked from a date set field). 
I've created a control containing month names `(Jan, Feb,....)`. The problem is that control values seems to be sorted in an alphabetical order `(Apr, Aug, Dec,....)` - this is not user friendly at all.

I've tried both setups (specific values, values linked from db), but with the same result

Any idea how to have list elements sorted i.e. by month_id?

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is prefix month name by month number like

```
201901 - Jan
201902 - Feb
```

Comment: I know - i use 1. Jab 2. Feb etc. But - it is not a true solution, rather a workaround. What i miss in Quicksight is mapping between control label and control value....

Comment: I miss that too. I workaround this by including the value in the label and extracing it in a computed field. But it is both a workaround and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

What you're observing is correct - QuickSight will not allow you to define a sorting logic for values populated for a Control. They will be always sorted in an ascending alphanumeric order.

For your use-case, I recommend you work-around this by prefixing/replacing month names with month numbers

```
01 - Jan
02 - Feb
03 - Mar
```